# preventing repetitive number combinations. Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of random numbers. Since its random, I want to iterate through that list and prevent any direct (following) repetition of the previous combination of **only** two numbers. For ex:

- I have this list = 7, 4, 3, 7, 1, 6...
- I will set the first two numbers as first comparison pairs (7 4)
- Now I am at index 2 and the number is 3, so does 3 exist in the previous combination (7 4)?
- no, so I will save it for the next comparison, until it become pair with another number
- Then, is 7 exist on (7 4)?
- yes, then loop through the list and look for a number that doesn't exist in (7 4)
- I found in index 4 number 1, so now take that number and swap it with 7, and since you have a unique two numbers, change the comparison to (3 7)
- and it keeps repeating until, i get a list of combined numbers of which no two combination would have the same numbers that the one before it already have.
- eventually, I should get something like, 7  4  3  1  7  6...

But my result show the following: 7, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 10, 4, 4, **7**

the 2nd 7 is not on the right place!!

My code looks fine to me, but the output is not what I quite expects! **I don't want a complete non-duplicate ordered set (Hash-set)! I need it to be the way I explained!!**

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] list = {7, 4, 3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 10};
  int[] lastCombination = {-1, -1}; //initial var
  int[] currentCombination = new int[2]; //temp

  int currentIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (lastCombination[0] == -1 && lastCombination[1] == -1) {
      lastCombination[0] = list[i];
      lastCombination[1] = list[++i];

    } else {
      if (list[i] != lastCombination[0] && list[i] != lastCombination[1]) { //i is not used
        if (currentIndex == 1) {
          currentCombination[currentIndex] = list[i];
          currentIndex = 0;
        } else {
          currentCombination[currentIndex] = list[i];
          currentIndex++;
        }

      } else { //i is used
        boolean isNotUnique = true;
        int next = i + 1;

        while (isNotUnique) {
          if (next <= (list.length - 1)) {
            if (list[next] != lastCombination[0] && list[next] != lastCombination[1]) {
              int temp = list[i];
              list[i] = list[next];
              list[next] = temp;
              i = i - 1;
              isNotUnique = false;
            } else {
              next++;
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("REACHED THE END");
            isNotUnique = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Original: 7, 4, 3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 10");
  System.out.print("Modified; ");
    for (int i : list) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you want a java.util.HashSet (or maybe java.util.LinkedHashSet if order is important)

Comment: no, I don't want to prevent duplicates, i just want each two direct combinations to be different than each other, but the numbers can repeat later. Also, I dont want it in order

Comment: I think we need a better description of your intent, not your algorithm for achieving that intent. It sounds like you're just saying that if list[n] is the same as list[n-2] or list[n-3] you want to discard it...?

Comment: @keshlam you can think of it as of pairs comparison, So, (7 4) (3 7) the second pair of numbers should **not** have the same number/s from the first one, but other pairs can (if they were not exactly next to the pair compared to)...etc

Comment: Ok, that's only slightly more complicated to check; the forbidden cases are (x[n]==x[n-2]&x[n-1]==x[n-3])|(x[n]==x[n-3)&x[n-1]==x[n-2]), right? It isn't clear what you want to do when one of those cases arises; there may not always be a solution...

Comment: I think you're making it more complex than it has to be by copying things out into the Combination buffers... And you can just start scanning from the second pair rather than playing games with a -1,-1 dummy value.